# Return the index of a giving string in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, element

i'm new at javascript, but, as i'm working in some arrow functions, i can't see why this block of code i wrote does not work. The idea here was to create a function that returns an array with the indexes when the second argument is found.

```
const materials = ['Hydrogen','Helium','Lithium','Beryllium'];

function index_same_element_as(){
  return arguments[0].map(argument => is_equal_to(argument, argument[1]))
}

console.log(index_same_element_as(materials,"2"))                      

// expected output: Array [false, false, false, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const materials = ['Hydrogen','Helium','Lithium','Beryllium'];

const index_same_element_as = (list, searchItem) => {
  return list.map(item => item === searchItem)
}

console.log(index_same_element_as(materials,"2"))
```

Or you can try this.

```
const materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];

function index_same_element_as() {
  return arguments[0]
    .map((argument, index) => argument === arguments[1])
}

console.log(index_same_element_as(materials, "2"))
console.log(index_same_element_as(materials, "Helium"))
```

Comment: Maybe explain how this works. I’m not exactly sure how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array and return its index when the element is equal to the second parameters, else return -1. After mapping, you filter and reject the index of -1

Moreover, in the comparison part, it must be

```
is_equal_to(argument, arguments[1])

// not
is_equal_to(argument, argument[1])
                              ^
```

```js
const materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];

function is_equal_to(x, y) {
  return x === y
}

function index_same_element_as() {
  return arguments[0]
    .map((argument, index) => is_equal_to(argument, arguments[1]) ? index : -1)
    .filter(index => index !== -1)
}

console.log(index_same_element_as(materials, "2"))
console.log(index_same_element_as(materials, "Lithium"))
```